# Yet another Pascal triangle in Python written in functional programming pattern

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, functional-programming

Here is my implementation of a Pascal program, which is used to print an n-order Pascal triangle. This is actually an exercise I came up with to familiarize myself with Python's [Functional Programming Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functional.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import operator
from itertools import starmap, tee
from functools import lru_cache


def pairwise(iterable):
    """
    s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2,s3), ...
    https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
    """
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

@lru_cache()
def pascal_row(n):
    """
    Print the nth row of a Pascal triangle
    """
    if n < 2:
        return (x for x in [1])
    else:
        def dispatch():
            yield 1
            yield from starmap(operator.add, pairwise(pascal_row(n-1)))
            yield 1
        return dispatch()


def pascal(n):
    """
    Print an n-order Pascal triangle
    """
    for i in range(1, n):
        print(pascal_row(i))

print([x for x in pascal_row(500)])
```

Is this the right way of functional programming? Also, I want you to tell me how to make this piece of code clearer :)

Comment: I don't get how to use your `pascal` function. It just prints a bunch of generator expressions. Also, after the code has run, trying to call `list(pascal_row(n))` with any n gives inconsistent behaviour. Try calling `list(pascal_row(140))` followed by `list(pascal_row(100))`, followed by `list(pascal_row(140))` again. The two results are completely different. Also, the `list(pascal_row(100))` call returns `[]`, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: @Graipher Thanks for spotting so many errors for me! The inconsistency of `pascal_row` can be fixed by removing `@lru_cache()`, and  I have to admit that my `pascal` function is wrong :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for `lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) you'll see that it says that `it can save time when an expensive or I/O bound function is periodically called with the same arguments`. You keep calling `pascal_row` with different arguments and the cache will miss all the time. This can be seen if you put this at the end of your program the line:

`print(pascal_row.cache_info())`

Output:

`CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=500, maxsize=128, currsize=128)`

The only other thing I'd say is that you don't really need the `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` line, UTF8 is the default and that's what you're using anyway.